# How can I align to the right opening using moderncv?

Tags: latex

Hello I am using moderncv with Latex. Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}     
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{red}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,right=1cm,left=1cm]{geometry}




\name{}{}

\begin{document}

\recipient{\ }{\ }
\date{}
\opening{Name of the company}
\closing{}

\makelettertitle

\textbf{}


\end{document}
```

And I would like actually that `\opening{Name of the company}` will be align to the right.

Could you help me ?

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}% <cmd>
  {\raggedright\@opening}% <search>
  {\raggedleft\@opening}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

*after* loading

```
\moderncvstyle{banking}
```